# How to get autocomplete result in another autoscaled div?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I want to get the autocomplete results in another autoscaled (height) div.

Here is my code :

```
var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++"
    ];
    $( "#search" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        open: function(event, ui) {
          $('ul.ui-autocomplete').removeAttr('style').hide().appendTo('.searchSuggest').show();
        }
    });

<div class="searchSuggest"></div>
<div class="anotherDiv"></div>
```

All is ok except the **searchSuggest** div that is not scaled (height), so my results appear on the next div. I want to know how to autoscale my **searchSuggest** div.

Any idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: What you mean by autoscale exactly. Can you explain it more?

Comment: In fact it appears that when you ask the results to be appended to the **searchSuggest** div, it adds 'position:relative' to it and 'position:absolute' (kind of) to the results div. So in the end, the results div recover the **anotherDiv** div. In fact I don't want the results div to be in 'position:absolute' but I want it direclty into the **searchSuggest** div. I don't know if I'm clear enough... Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use the jQuery UI CSS framework ?

There are IMO two things that prevents the container **searchSuggest** from growing with the result list (a `.ui-menu` widget actually)

- the `ul.ui-autocomplete` has `position: absolute`, which means the element is out of the flow
- it also has `float: left`, as well as the menu items

You can override those settings:

```css
.searchSuggest .ui-autocomplete {
    position: relative;
    float: none;
}

.searchSuggest .ui-menu .ui-menu-item {
    float: none;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/vpWf7/)**

Comment: All I have to say is : YOU ROCK! THANKS A LOT!! Et si tu es Belge et que tu parles français, sache que je te remercie énormément car tu m'enlèves une grosse épine du pied ! ;-)

Comment: Avec plaisir ;-) N'oublie pas d'accepter la réponse pour fermer la question et de voter. Glad it helped !